# Which form was submitted?

Tags: forms, submit

If we have a following html file which accesses my tester.php file via form action:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body> 

<h1>Three Forms</h1>


    <p>Employee</p>

    <form id="form1" name="form" method="post" action="tester.php">

        <label for="name1">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name1">
<br/>

<label for="email1">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email1"/>
<br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
<br/><br/>


<p>Customer</p>

<form id="form2" name="form" method="post" action="tester.php">

        <label for="name2">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name2">
<br/>

<label for="email2">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email2"/>
<br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
<br/><br/>


<p>Supplier</p>

<form id="form3" name="form" method="post" action="tester.php">

        <label for="name3">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name3">
<br/>

<label for="email3">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email3"/>
<br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
<br/><br/>


</body>
</html>
```

If we don't have access to html file (cannot be changed) and user has disabled javascript, how can I know which form was submitted? Only tester.php can be modified.

Comment: If the only thing differentiating them is the `id` (which isn't sent with the form data), then there is no feasible way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You have no way of knowing that since the same parameters `name` and `email` are POSTed from all the forms.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the form is not sent with the $_POST data.

The only way of telling would be to rename the name attributes on the input to:

name1,name2,name3, etc.